# Cannot install Google Chrome Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox, flash, adobe

I was trying to watch ABC iview using Firefox, but I was getting poor playback like I had a very poor link when I have good bandwidth.  The playback would run fine for a few minutes and then revert to a photo story mode of occasional still images for a few minutes and back to normal for a few more and so on.

I tried to install Google Chrome from Google Play which would download but nothing happens when I press the Green Install Button.  I used the Ubuntu software centre to install Chromium Browser which seems to have no Flash player extension.  Searched for Adobe Flash from its extension search within Chromium and only found flash for Youtube.

I tried on advice from here:

> However, if you still want the most up-to-date version, you can add
>   the PPA:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
> ```
>
> This will install the actual player, but it still needs an extra file. >This file is the actual pepperflash library used by the player. To get it, >you can use a PPA:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
> ```

The last line `sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer` reported not finding all the files.

This changed nothing in Chromium but completely stopped Firefox from even starting to run a clip.

What Browser should I use for proper iView functionality with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I see quite some confusion about Flash. Please see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) about Flash on Ubuntu.

Comment: Try downloading and installing Google Chrome for Linux from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: Yes, do as @NickWeinberg says. FYI you will need to install `libappindicator1` or maybe `libappindicator2` first, otherwise it will fail the install due to missing dependencies

Comment: Realised that the Chrome version I was trying to install was 64 bit and my 16.04 is 32 bit.  Got confused because i was originally trying to install 64 bit 16.04 however for some reason, I never discovered why, my machine would not boot off the 16.04 DVD, however the same machine booted fine of a 14.04 disk which I installed and upgraded to 16.04.  I forgot that both were 32 bit version even though the PC supports 64 bit OS.  So I found a 32 bit chrome and installed the older version which works.  Other machines booted OK from the 64 bit 16.04 so I don't understand why just one PC would not?

Comment: Even with Chrome installed this machine does not run ABC Live View properly where video reverts to still images with audio OK..  I have Gig ethernet to the ADSL switch which has fast ADSL internet so why am I getting this poor performance and what do I need to do to resolve?